# Server 2012 R2 - hidden Share$ not accessible

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

None of our hidden shares (\Server\Profile$) are accessible from the client machines. We can connect to them fine from the server but not from the win 7 client machines.

Not a firewall issue, I have tried with that turned off.

Not a security issue, "Everyone" has full share permissions and NTFS permissions.

Nothing in event logs to denote an error, checked System, Application, Security.

Have tried creating new shares and same issue, all ok until make it hidden then access is denied!

Is this a server 2012 R2 issue? Test exactly the same thing in server 2012 and all works fine, just on R2 that the problems exist.

Anyone out there using hidden$ shares in 2012 R2 and got it working?

Nick

Comment: `Anyone out there using hidden$ shares in 2012 R2 and got it working?` Yes, got it working normally without issues

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that users have the following permissions:

- Read extended attributes
- Read permission